# Cannot set default background image for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using a `MFMailComposeViewController` to compose a mail and add an attachment in my app.

I've got this code in my `AppDelegate.m`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0x0A/255.0f green:0x13/255.0f blue:0x1A/255.0f alpha:1]];
```

Then I'm using this code to create the  `MFMailComposeViewController` in another `UIViewController`

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[mailViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, the `UINavigationBar` in the `MFMailComposeViewController` is dark, how come it doesn't "reset" itself to the background I specify before presenting it? Is it inheriting the color of the current `UIViewController`?

Comment: It is dark because you set the background image to nil. What do you want it to be?

Comment: @JasonNam Thought I read somewhere that it would reset the color back to default. That's my goal, to have it appear just like it would in the native mail app when composing

Comment: Ahh you may assigning nil to the tintColor not background image.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UINavigationBar`'s `barTintColor` to `nil`. It will remove the custom tint color.